# Aggregating column in view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with "HoursCompleted" and is calculated daily.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    PersonId INT NOT NULL,
    DateValue DATE NOT NULL,
    HoursToday DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL
)
```

What I need to do is create a view that shows those fields, as well as a TotalHoursForPerson.

So, I can Select from View, where PersonId = x, and it returns:

```
Id|PersonId|DateValue|HoursToday|Total
1,1,'01-JAN', 5, 5
2,1,'02-JAN', 8, 13
3,1,'03-JAN', 2, 15
etc
etc
```

But I am unsure if I can get that 'total' column.

Comment: I hope you dont need Id in the view. You can use select query with sum(HoursToday) as DayHours  group by PersonId, DateDalue.

Comment: Since the answer of @ThomasHaratyk works for you, you might add `SQLServer2012` to  the tags, since `SUM()` with `ORDER BY` is not supported in prior versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to achieve a cumulative sum, here is one concise and efficient way to do it :

```
CREATE VIEW YourView
AS
SELECT Id, PersonId, DateValue, HoursToday, 
       SUM(HoursToday) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY Id /* or date */) AS Total
FROM MyTable
```

Then, to query the view :

```
SELECT * FROM YourView WHERE PersonId = 42
```